# "Use of unassigned local variable 'ponderThread'" on a previously initialized variable

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've been writing an AI that plays chess recently. The AI is designed to run two separate instances, each connected to a client server. The server calls a run function for each AI in turn. What I'm trying to do is write code that ponders while the other AI is making its move. However, I've come across an issue. I'll show the code so as to make explaining said issue easier:

```
public override bool run()
{
    PonderSearch ponderSearch = new PonderSearch();
    Thread ponderThread;
    AIMove bestMove = null;
    int Depth = 0;

    // Print the board
    if (moves.Length < 2)
    {
        theBoard.Print();
    }

    if (!FirstTurn)
    {
        AIMove lastMove = new AIMove(AI.moves[0]);
        Depth = ponderSearch.Depth;

        foreach (MoveTable result in ponderSearch.TheTable)
        {
            if (result.TheMove == lastMove)
            {
                bestMove = result.TheResult.Move;
            }
        }

        // End thread
        ponderThread.Abort();
        ponderThread.Join();
    }

    // Looks through information about the players
    for (int p = 0; p < players.Length; p++)
    {
        Console.Write(players[p].getPlayerName());

        // if playerID is 0, you're white, if its 1, you're black
        if (players[p].getId() == playerID())
        {
            Console.Write(" (ME)");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" time remaining: " + players[p].getTime());
    }

    AIMove otherPMove = new AIMove();
    AIPiece pieceMoved = new AIPiece();

    // if there has been a move, print the most recent move
    if (moves.Length > 0)
    {
        // Update the board state with previous move
        theBoard = theBoard.Update();
        pieceMoved = theBoard.GetPiece((short)moves[0].getToRank(),
            (short)moves[0].getToFile());
        otherPMove = new AIMove(moves[0], pieceMoved);

        if (lastMoves.Count >= 8)
        {
            lastMoves.RemoveAt(7);
        }

        lastMoves.Insert(0, otherPMove);
    }

    // Generate move
    Search theSearch = new Search(lastMoves);

    if (!FirstTurn)
    {
        theSearch.Update(Depth, bestMove);
    }

    AIMove theMove = theSearch.Minimax(theBoard, (short)playerID());

    // Update last 8 moves
    if (lastMoves.Count >= 8)
    {
        lastMoves.RemoveAt(7);
    }

    lastMoves.Insert(0, theMove);

    if (theMove != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Move Chosen:");
        theMove.Print();
        theBoard = theBoard.Move(theMove, (short)playerID());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No move available");
    }

    theBoard.Print();

    // Begin pondering
    ponderSearch = new PonderSearch(lastMoves, (short)playerID(), theBoard, theMove);
    ponderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ponderSearch.Ponder));
    ponderThread.Start();
    FirstTurn = false;
    return true;
}
```

Anyway, as written, the compiler throws multiple errors saying my Thread hasn't been initialized but the point is that the function runs multiple times, ending the thread that was started in the most recent call at the beginning of the current one.

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks,

EDIT: The error I get is:

```
Error   4   Use of unassigned local variable 'ponderThread' C:\Users\...\AI.CS  52  13  csclient
```

Comment: the title of the question itself does not make any sense!

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the Task Parallelism Library in .NET for doing multi-threaded programming as it makes the abstraction of working with "tasks" that run on different threads much easier to interact with. Continuations, waiting for tasks etc are much simpler to accomplish.

Comment: @AppDeveloper: Sorry if my title was hard to understand. That was the best way I could think of to describe my issue

Comment: If you get the compiler error, post the exact error to get help. Same thing applies to runtime exception also

Comment: @JesseCarter: I don't think that anyone should use TPL without understand basic threading first. You'll just shoot yourself in the foot as TPL may or may not execute tasks synchronously. i.e. your code might or might not work if you have thread synchronization problems. It's more obvious with a vanilla thread.

Comment: I'll be honest and say I have little experience with threading. I know enough to create and manipulate them but a lot of the inner workings are still akin to black magic.

Comment: Why are you calling `ponderThread.Abort()` without initializing it? What are you trying to Abort. Also why are you trying to `Join` an aborted thread?

Comment: As I explained, the run function is called repeatedly (about once every 30 seconds). The original thread has to be initialized at the end of the last call of the function, and ended at the beginning of the next call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with threading. It's a simple scoping issue. All local variables (declared inside a method) is typically put on the stack and cleaned up when the method exists.

Hence the `ponderThread` will be garbage collected after the `run()` method have exited. So the next time your method enter it will have the member variable `FirstTurn` set to true while `ponderThread` is uninitialized as it's a local variable.

A quick fix is to change the `ponderThread` variable to a class variable (called member variable in C#).

That will however give you thread synchronization problems as you are going to share state between two threads.

I suggest that you read up a bit more about threads before going further.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't consider making the thread a class variable instead of a method variable but that fixed my issues.